# Display text file content listed in listbox to text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

my knowledge of C#(ASP.Net) is limited and i am really trying hard to figure this problem out...

what i did was create a `listbox` and populate it with a `.txt` or `xml` file from path D:\test with this code

```
     string path = "D:\\test";
    files = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); //no need to define any parameters
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(files[i].FullName));
```

once the `listbox` displays the all .txt files from the directory, i want to select a text file and  that selected file will show the internal content or text of a notepad file in a textbox. i write this code in `selectedindexchanged` event of `listbox` but when i click on `.txt` file inside `listbox` it shows nothing in textbox. Plz help me. Thank you.

```
    string fullNameOfFile = files[ListBox1.SelectedIndex].FullName;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fullNameOfFile))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
    TextBox1.Text = "Content of file " + fullNameOfFile + " is:\r\n\"" + sb.ToString();
```

Comment: if you know the full path of file. Then just do TextBox1.Text = "Content of file " + fullNameOfFile + " is:\r\n\"" + File.ReadAllLines(fullNameOfFile);

Answer (score 0):

Use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) method. Replace all of your code with just one line.

```
TextBox1.Text = "Content of file " + fullNameOfFile + " is:\r\n\"" + File.ReadAllLines(fullNameOfFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this but not working when i select a any .txt file inside a listbox it shows nothing in textbox.

Comment: Guy anyone can give me the solution for above.